# MySQL 5.6 individual timezones for each database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

How can I set individual timezone for each database on MySQL server?

Is it possible that for each table in one database can change timesamp (i.e. EST) keep same and for another tables in another database keep same time stamp (i.e. UTC)

Do anyone have such experience?

Many Thanks,

Comment: This might be of some help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916747/set-mysql-database-timezone-to-gmt

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps are stored in UTC. Timezones can be set on a per-connection basis. Timestamps are converted to UTC for storage and converted back to the connection timezone for retrieval. There is no finer grained setting.