# SQL Finding upcoming date and time

Tags: sql

SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE eventdate >= DATE(NOW()) 
AND eventtime > TIME(NOW()) 
ORDER BY eventdate ASC, eventtime ASC;
```

The goal is to select the event that is coming up next. It works just fine so long as there are not two events on the same date. For example:

```
Event 1, 11/17/2016 7:00am
Event 2, 11/17/2016 2:00pm
Event 3, 11/18/2016 9:00am
```

I want to select event 2 since it is passed 7:00 am on the 17th. The statement above would still select event 1.

Comment: Please do not tag this question with databases that you are not using. I have removed those tags. Please add only the tag for the database you *are* using.

Comment: Not sure I understood what you are looking for, but you may add a LIMIT 2.

Comment: I do not want to select event 1, since it has already happened. But the statement above is selecting it.

Comment: Are the columns on the database of type DATE and TIME or have you stored the date in a VARCHAR or somethng equally as unhelpful

Comment: They are type date and time.

Comment: What database manager / software are you using (mySQL, SSMS, Oracle, Access)? What does `SELECT NOW()` return?

Comment: There must be something else going on here because when I test that query on MYSQL it works just as you say you want it to. It selects only the 1 row containing Event2

Comment: @Fritz That is the problem. It is two hours behind. How do I set it to EST?

Comment: @BrianBreeden what are you using software wise?

Comment: @Fritz I am new to this, but I am currently using PHPmyAdmin

Comment: The original query you gave is simply wrong, regardless of the 2 hour _gap_ you see. @user2693928 has the right solution. The question is just about where the 2 hour gap comes from. Is the server running in a different time zone than where you are?

Comment: Yes. I believe the time zone of the server is different than where I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As determined in the comments, the issue lies with the timezone currently used by the server where the database resides. Because of this, and that you are using PHPmyAdmin, I believe you do not have the authority to change the server timezone.

Your possible solutions are:

- Use data that is already in MST (UTC-07) or whatever time zone the server is on
- Use the current data and subtract 2 hours or [convert the data to a time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38899741/5203406)
- Rewrite the query to use NOW() + 2 hours

Comment: Suggest you remove the "Change (or find who can change) the server timezone". That would just move the problem to some other user which is not in the same time zone.. Btw, this is why in most cases it makes sense to store UTC date/time in the database, not local date/time. Everyone agrees on the current UTC time...

Comment: Noted and updated. I was answering under the impression that this was a personal project when I shouldn't have made that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE eventdate > DATE(NOW())
OR
    (eventdate = DATE(NOW()) AND eventtime > TIME(NOW()) )

ORDER BY eventdate ASC, eventtime ASC;
```

Basically you compare if date is in the future(tomorrow) or date is today and time is passed.

If your date is in the future you don't care about the time in this case.

Try it.

Comment: Looks like the problem is that the NOW() is two hours behind. Any idea on how to change the time to EST?

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916747/set-mysql-database-timezone-to-gmt

Answer (score 0):

I would need the value stored in `eventdate` and `eventtime` `fields` in your `table` in context to your example. because if you are checking `time > TIME(NOW())`, it should not pick this event if time is passed.

Comment: I see the first <code>time</code> is set at 8:06 when the event is at 7:00 am. If the code is running between 7:00 and 8:06, it will take the first event of the day as well. The timezone doesn't seems to be an issue as SQL statement is using NOW() function which is the function executed at the server time. It all depends what actually is the exact time at the server and if there is any time difference between place of event and server's time.